Why did a Russian court fine Google $20 decillion?
A Russian court recently fined Google US$20,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (20 Decillion). That's about 181,000,000,000,000,000,000 (181 Sextillion) times the GDP of the entire world. It's pretty obvious that fine isn't getting paid. The decision was due Google blocking Russian state channels and it seems to be endorsed by the Russian government,  which has acknowledged that the fine is a symbolic gesture. So, my question is, what's the point of demanding an outrageous fine which is impossible to pay? What does Russia actually hope to gain by doing that?

Russia doesn't really have Rule of Law anymore, so any action out of a Russian court with international implications likely as not was arrived at for political reasons. From a legal standpoint, they are a noise machine.

Why Qs can be answered on multiple levels. IDK how common is for Russian courts to put such high fines or such "geometric" rules for non-payment... from already bankrupt companies, as Google's Russia subsidiary already is, according to the piece you linked. (And all their assets [in Russia] have already been seized, also according to the piece.)
The political message they want to send seems to be, in the words of Russia's presidency spokesman:

“I actually can’t even pronounce that number,” Peskov said. “Rather, this sum is filled with symbolism. These demands demonstrate the essence of our channels’ grievances against Google.”

So, Russia's government feels like nothing on earth could repay the wrong that they perceive Google has done them. It's a way of saying to Google: "never come back to Russia".

Max's answer is correct that others believe that it's part of a wider lawfare by Russia against sanctions. Essentially they sue Western companies first in Russia for an easy win, then use that to sue them in various countries (like in Africa) that are at least partly pro-Russia. Western countries' legal system have mostly blocked those attempts, but if [some] Western companies are driven out of Africa, it probably counts as some kind of win for Russia, which aims to expands its sphere of influence there.
Also, Google appears to claim that the funds seized from it Russia more than covered the fine (at the time):

The Telegraph revealed in August that bailiffs acting for Moscow had seized more than $100 million from the bankrupt entity to fund Putin’s war machine.
In court documents Google said Russia had handed the assets to sanctioned TV channels including Tsargrad, whose owner Mr Malofeev has been described as the “Orthodox oligarch”, and state-owned RT.
In the filings, Google said: “The bailiffs seized more than $100 million of Google Russia’s assets, even though the amount purportedly due under the judgement at the time was less than $12.5m (1 billion roubles).
“Tsargrad received 1 billion roubles from the seizure, which it said it would use to support Russia’s war in Ukraine.”
The technology giant is also fighting efforts by Russian broadcasters to enforce the fines in foreign jurisdictions, including South Africa, Turkey and Serbia.

Basically, if Google is believed, Russia can never have enough.
OTOH, in one of the other pieces on this, Peskov was also quoted as saying:

“The company should not restrict our broadcasters on their platform,” he added, on his daily briefing call with reporters. “This should be a reason for the Google leadership to pay attention to this and improve the situation.”

So, perhaps he's suggesting that the lawsuits in 3rd (Russia-friendly) countries could be dropped, if Google/YouTube were to allow a platform for the sanctioned Russian entities. (Whether Russia has the legal mechanisms to undo the domestic fines at this point, I'm less sure, but perhaps "where there's will there's a way".) Anyhow, the more important issue for Google/YouTube is probably whether they could do this without exposing themselves to Western legal/political risk.

Apparently, the court decision sets the fines to grow geometrically, which leads to chessboard and wheat kind of scenario:

Every day, the amount of claims against the company increases due to penalties. Soon, they may reach googol — a unit with 100 zeros — a mathematical term that became a source of inspiration when choosing the name of the Google search engine.

https://habr.com/ru/news/855744/

My very rough calculations indicate that it will take a full 13 years to reach $1 google (or a google rubles). But when that happens that will be funny.

But why did they set it up like that?

I guess that's "inner motivations of people", but not expecting a reasonable fine to be paid could be a motive for assigning an unreasonable one.

That still begs the question of what would they gain by having a fine that can't be paid.

@JoeW Well, possibly, they did indeed expect google to pay the more reasonable fine originally, and set up the doubling per week system so it would be done quickly. Since google decided not to, the fine got to an unreasonable amount, but that wasn't their original goal. (Not saying this is the reason but this seems like a logical idea).

1^100 = Googol, not to be confused with Google

@Jonathan 10^100 not 1^100 which equals 1.

@user182601 You're right, I combined 1e100 and 10^100 :)

Russia demanded Google reinstate one of its channels and put an astreinte (a penalty that increases daily) which ballooned to 20 decillions. It is using it to push Google towards allowing Russian propaganda on its platform. Based on these demands South Africa has attached Google assets in SA (prevents it from selling them or moving funds out of the country). Russia is using this to get other countries friendly to it do same things as SA, to inconvenience Google and attempt to make them give in to Russian demands. They highball with these demands but will meet in a practical zone where maybe Google just stops blocking Russian propaganda or something. No one is taking seriously this fine like they don't take seriously Medvedev's drunken nuclear threats.

But that amount of money is not a demand google could possibly give into even if they wanted to

"astreinte" doesn't seem to be an English word. I'll pardon your French though. :p

@Starship yes and they don't expect them to pay obviously. its just a negotiations tactic

@max But what are they negotiating for other than for Google to listen to them

@Starship they want google to stop banning of Russian propaganda youtube channels. Presumably the threat is 1) youtube is banned in Russia, 2) Russia-friendly countries can mess with google's assets like what happened here in SA

@264champagnebottlesonice why use many words when one foreign word works
